# Splitting a list into 2 or N sub-lists based on some condition

Tags: elixir

I have a list or array. How can I break it down into 2 or N sublists based on some condition? I haven't found anything related to that in the documentation.

Comment: "a list or array"? If you're coding in Elixir, you don't have an array--you have a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Enum.split_with/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#split_with/2) splits the enumerable in two lists according to the given function:

```
Enum.split_with([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], fn(x) -> rem(x, 2) == 0 end)
{[4, 2, 0], [5, 3, 1]}
```

Or in older versions of Elixir use [Enum.reduce/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3):

```
Enum.reduce([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], {[], []}, fn(x, {xs, ys}) ->
  if rem(x, 2) == 0, do: {[x | xs], ys}, else: {xs, [x | ys]} end)
{[4, 2, 0], [5, 3, 1]}
```